# Django order by highest number of likes

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a page where people can see the highest rated article, there is one problem: when I filter the number of likes of an article that was also liked by another user it creates a copy of the upvoted article.

[image]

What I want is to order the articles of the blog by the highest number of likes.

**models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default='1')
    [... unrelated fields ...]
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="likes")

    [... unrelated function ...]
```

**views.py**

```
def article_ordered_by_likes(request):
    context = {'article': Article.objects.order_by('-likes')}
    return render(request, 'article_ordered_by_likes.html', context)

def like_button(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        id = request.POST.get('pk', None)

        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=id)

        if article.likes.filter(id=user.id).exists():
            article.likes.remove(user)
        else:
            article.likes.add(user)

        context = {'likes_count': article.total_likes}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type='application/json')
```

**article_ordered_by_likes.html**

```
{% for a in article %}
    [... unrelated html ...]
    <h2>{{ a.titre }}</h2>
    <span id="count{{ a.id }}">{{ a.total_likes }}</span>
    <input type="button" class="like" id="{{ a.id }}" value="Like" />
{% endfor %}
```

Why is Django creating the same post multiple times? How can I order the articles by the highest number of likes without having this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django is not creating multiple posts. Its because of that query.
If you want to sort based on like count then you should do like this,

```
Article.objects.annotate(like_count=Count('likes')).order_by('-like_count')
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use `annotate`. Here's how you can order by the number of users who "liked" an article:

```
Article.objects.annotate(like_count=Count('likes')).order_by('-like_count')
```