# How do I order by highest number of likes on blog posts?

Tags: django

I've seen similar questions to this but they only mention how to do it for function-based views, not in the `Meta` class, where the default ordering is set.

Example: [Django order by highest number of likes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097130/django-order-by-highest-number-of-likes)

I have a `Post` model which I'm currently ordering by date, however I want to order it by the count of the number of likes. What would I change `ordering = ('-date',)` to in order to achieve this?

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, default=None, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="post_likes", blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

   
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-date',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a manager that will annotate and order by:

```
from django.db.models import Count


class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .alias(nlikes=Count('likes'))
            .order_by('-nlikes')
        )


class Post(models.Model):
    # …
    objects = PostManager()
```

You can then still use `Post._base_manager.all()` to avoid ordering.